# Debuggear consultas de eloquent en laravel

Tags: laravel-5, base-de-datos, eloquent

Realizo transacciones con eloquent de laravel 5.5 y quisiera depurar la consulta real por ejemplo:

```
objeto::all();
```

y quisiera ver la real consulta por ejemplo

```
select * from objeto
```

de igual manera para insert y update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber que consultas se ejecutan y cuales son en formato SQL , podría utilizar el fascade `DB` de la siguiente  forma en el archivo `routes/web.php` *(antes de todas las rutas definidas)*

```
DB::listen(function($query){
  //Imprimimos la consulta ejecutada
  echo "<pre> {$query->sql } </pre>";
});

Route::get(...
/* Más rutas */
```

Esto está especificado en la [documentación de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database#listening-for-query-events) donde también tiene la opción de colocar el `Listen` en el `AppServiceProvider`.

Comment: y de que manera lo puedo hacer en el controlador, quiero realizar un log interno y ver cada transacción a la base de datos

Answer (score 1):

a partir en laravel 5.* podes hacer de la siguiente manera :

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();

objeto::all();

$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

En la variable ´queries´ vas a tener todas las queries que se ejecutaron desde que ejecutaste la función  ´enableQueryLog()´ hasta que las imprimiste.

Te dejo el link de laravel donde lo explica 
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging .

Saludos